# How to parse date time?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to parse a date column that is currently type string. It is in the format of

2005-04-24T09:12:49Z

I have Spark version 2.1. And I've tried the following

```
spark.sql("SELECT TO_DATE(Date) FROM df").show()
```

This returns 
**2005-04-24** 
but no timestamp.

Next I tried

```
val ts = unix_timestamp($"Date", "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp")
df.withColumn("Date", ts).show()
```

This returned all nulls

Then I tried

```
spark.sql("select TO_DATE(Date_Resulted, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ') AS date from lab").show()
```

but this just returned the error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Invalid number of arguments for function to_date; line 1 pos 7
```

There has to be an easy way to parse this string date column to return type DateTime. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways to get datetime in Spark.

Let's use the following sample data:

```
val df=Seq("2005-04-24T09:12:49Z").toDF("time_stamp")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
```

### Date from timestamp

```
//in spark sql api
spark.sql("select to_date(time_stamp)dt from tmp").show()

//in dataframe api
df.withColumn("dt",to_date('time_stamp)).select("dt").show()

Result:
//+----------+
//|        dt|
//+----------+
//|2005-04-24|
//+----------+
```

### get datetime from timestamp - Using from_unixtime and unix_timestamp functions

```
//in spark sql api
spark.sql("""select timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time_stamp,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")) as ts from tmp""").show()

//in dataframe api
df.withColumn("dt",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('time_stamp,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").cast("timestamp")).select("dt").show()

// Result:
// +-------------------+
// |                 ts|
// +-------------------+
// |2005-04-24 09:12:49|
// +-------------------+
```

### get datetime from timestamp - Using unix_timestamp function

```
//in spark sql api    
spark.sql("""select timestamp(unix_timestamp(time_stamp,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'")) as ts from tmp""").show()

//in dataframe api
df.withColumn("dt",unix_timestamp('time_stamp,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'").cast("timestamp")).select("dt").show()

// Result:
// +-------------------+
// |                 ts|
// +-------------------+
// |2005-04-24 09:12:49|
// +-------------------+
```

### get datetime from timestamp - Using to_timestamp function

```
//in spark sql api
spark.sql("select to_timestamp(time_stamp)ts from tmp").show()

//in dataframe api
df.withColumn("dt",to_timestamp('time_stamp)).select("dt").show()

// Result:
// +-------------------+
// |                 ts|
// +-------------------+
// |2005-04-24 04:12:49|
// +-------------------+
```

### get datetime from timestamp - Using to_timestamp function with format specified

```
//in spark sql api
spark.sql("""select to_timestamp(time_stamp,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'")ts from tmp""").show()

//in dataframe api
df.withColumn("dt",to_timestamp($"time_stamp","yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'")).select("dt").show()

// Result:
// +-------------------+
// |                 ts|
// +-------------------+
// |2005-04-24 09:12:49|
// +-------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

this will work :

```
val df = Seq("2005-04-24T09:12:49Z").toDF("date")

df
  .withColumn("date_converted", to_timestamp($"date", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|                date|     date_converted|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|2005-04-24T09:12:49Z|2005-04-24 09:12:49|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```